# Как корректно написать новогоднее поздравление с номером года?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, прописная-строчная

Мое предположение:

> С новым, 2019, годом!

Грамота [поясняет](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/nauka_i_zhizn/28_802):

> «Новый год» — официальное название праздника, и если мы, подписывая открытку «С Новым годом!», имеем в виду именно название праздника, то пишем его, как и другие имена собственные, с заглавной (прописной, большой) буквы.
>   Если же имеется в виду начало нового календарного года, то в поздравлении «новый год» пишем со строчной буквы.

Наличие номера года склоняет нас ко второму варианту, а сам номер — это уточнение, поэтому выделяем его запятыми. Не думаю, что будет корректно видеть тут неоднородные определения "новый 2019", как, например, "новый большой помидор", так как 2019 год (в отличие от большого помидора) не может быть новым или слегка подпорченным.

Я понимаю "новый" как "следующий" (*С новым, 2019, годом!* =  *Со следующим, 2019, годом!*) Однако нигде написания с запятой не нашел. Может, "новый" можно понимать как "наступивший"? Тогда всех поздравляю с новым 2019 годом!

Comment: @МГ, в интернете может быть разное написание. Надо ориентироваться на надежные источники.

Comment: А я бы написала "С Новым годом-2019! "    Почему пишут "Олимпиада - 2018", а праздник нельзя?

Comment: @Людмила, "справка" также предлагает такой вариант. Но при этом говорит о том, что такой вариант верен орфографически, но не стилистически.

Comment: @МГ, кстати, в первоначальном своем ответе, "справка" предлагала писать так: "С Новым, 2016, годом. Т. е. с запятыми с двух сторон. Но потом появилась та статья, которую я привел. Там уже одна запятая. Ссылку дать не могу. Вбейте в Яндексе Вопрос № 249079 - С Новым годом! Вам придет список. В первой строке откроется ссылка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Та же Грамота [пишет](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/58-newyear):

> Как написать поздравление: с Новым 2016 годом или с новым 2016 годом? Нужны ли запятые?
>   Вопрос непростой. Будем разбираться.
>   Следует отметить, что название праздника – Новый год, а не Новый 2016 год. Какой из этого следует вывод?
>   Во-первых, поскольку 2016 год (пусть даже и новый) – это не название праздника (этой фразой мы поздравляем не с праздником Новый год, который отмечается ежегодно 1 января, а с наступлением собственно очередного года), слово новый здесь логично написать со строчной.
>   Во-вторых, слова две тысячи шестнадцатый выступают в роли пояснительного определения к слову новый, и поэтому между этими определениями требуется запятая: новый, 2016 год. (Ср. пример из справочника Д. Э. Розенталя «Пунктуация»: Вскоре мы вступим в новое, XXI столетие). Если запятую не поставить, то получится весьма странное по смыслу сочетание «новый (т. е. еще один) две тысячи шестнадцатый год», как будто в истории человечества такой год уже был и раньше.
>   Итак, если поздравлять с праздником, то поздравлять нужно с Новым годом. Если же поздравлять с наступлением очередного года, то поздравлять **с новым, 2016 годом**.

Answer (score 3):

На некоторых открытках пишут: **С Новым 2019 годом!**

И правильно делают. Я думаю, что никто не обижается, потому что запись всем понятна и графика смотрится красиво.

А правила в данном случае хороши для различения портфелей: "новый, кожаный" или "новый кожаный".

Общий праздник – это Новый год, но каждый Новый год в своем роде единственный для нас, **это тоже имя собственное** для наступающего года, **и в это имя может входить его название.** Всё логично.

Поэтому формальные правила здесь не стоит применять, и пусть каждый Новый год  имеет свою собственное эксклюзивное поздравление.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вношу изменение в свой ответ.

Я считаю, что существуют **две темы для поздравления:** (1) с праздником и (2) с новым календарным годом.

**Поздравление с праздником** пишется так: **С Новым годом!** Название года на поздравительных открытках указывается в стороне.

**Поздравление с новым календарным годом** можно записать следующим образом: **С новым, 2019 годом!** Этот вариант  удобно использовать в письмах.

Comment: Вы хотели сказать "**номер** может входить в его название"?

Comment: Именно это я и хочу сказать, но вот не знаю, как отнесется к этому Грамота.ру. А Вы, как я вижу, собираетесь  писать "С новым, 2019 годом"?  Думаю, что простые люди Вас не одобрят.

Comment: Логика спорная, но в реальной жизни нежелание "засорять" поздравление запятыми, кажется, побеждает .

Comment: А как насчет нежелания писать праздник со строчной буквы?

Comment: И это тоже, кажется, побеждает, хотя и не столь уверенно. Вариантов со строчной/прописной до сих пор гуляет немало.

Comment: @sharon, если ориентироваться на простых людей, в правилах будет разнобой. Во-вторых,действительно,  название праздника, как пишет Грамота.ру, Новый год, а не Новый 2016, к примеру.  Поэтому писать с прописной не имеет никаких оснований.

Comment: @Серж. Наступает новый, 2019 год.  По правилам написано?  Да, по правилам. Все довольны, в том числе и простые люди. Поздравляют же  обычно с праздником, а  не с наступлением очередного года.  Или так и надо писать: поздравляем с наступлением  нового, 2019 года, но ни на одной поздравительной открытке я такой записи не видела.  А  Вы где  напишите свою правильное поздравление?

Comment: @Sharon, лучше написать проще: с Новым годом!

Comment: Но если все же придется писать с цифрой, то только с запятой и со строчной.

Comment: Как только не пишут! С наступившим новым 2019 годом! С новым 2019-м годом! А вот текст. Картинки, открытки с Новым годом 2019: наилучшие поздравления друзьям и близким. Вот и наступил в России и по всему миру главный праздник года — Новый 2019 год.

Comment: @Sharon,вы правы, пишут по-разному. Пишут по незнанию. Но мы-то с вами знаем. Да и потом, почему вы несогласны с запятой? Ведь без запятой получается, что такой-то год уже был.

Comment: @Серж  Я изменила свой ответ, решив, что существуют две формы поздравления. И пользуясь случаем, поздравляю Вас с Новым годом. Надеюсь, что Вы будете чаще заходить на сайт, Вам здесь очень многие  рады

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо большое за поздравление! И вас с праздником! Я захожу каждый день. Просто порой сил не бывает отвечать. )))